# How can i fix a bootstrap row element with a property of display: flex, blocking my page from displaying on the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a Wordpress theme from scratch.
You will find my html and css code below.

Everything seems okay with my html and css, but when i preview the page on my browsers, both chrome and Mozilla firefox
nothing is showing up. Then i decide to do an element inspection on these pages.

<--My HTML CODE-->

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sx-12">
        <div class="header-container background-image text-center" 
 style="background-image: url(<?php header_image();?>);">
            <div class="header-content">
                <div class="nav-container">

                </div><!--.nav-container-->
            </div><!--.header-content-->           
        </div><!--.header-container-->        
    </div><!--.col-sx-12-->   
</div><!--.row-->    
</div><!--.container-fluid-->
```

/*
My CSS CODE
@package nuorigins
*/

### /*

Generic

---

*/

```
.background-image{
    background-position: center center; 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

### /*

### Header

*/

```
.header-container{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 250px;
}
```

I found out that the row tag as been blocking my page from displaying.

below is the element of the row from inspection:

```
.row{
    display: ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    ms-flexwrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Note that this is a row from bootstrap.

Now i noticed when i deactivate the display: flex; from the properties of the row, my page display fine.

I want anybody to please let me know. What is the problem with my bootstrap row?
Is it because my browser is not supporting the bootstrap row, or this is due to another problem from my bootstrap files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All browsers do display the Bootstrap grid (containers, rows and columns) fine. BS3 supports IE8+ and BS4 supports IE9+ and all other browsers.

Probably a typing bug. Use col-sm-12 (not col-sx-12).